# How to create map between string and a classifier object ptr

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I create a map between a string and a classifier, in this case, it is the SVM classifier in openCV. Essentially I am trying to convert a code from using opencv 2.3.1 to Opencv 3+

The old code is

```
map<string,CvSVM> class_classifier
```

I have tried with the cv::ml::SVM but the compiler complains that it is an abstract class. The error reads

> "second is a copy of the second object

```
map<string,cv::ml::SVM> class_classifier
```

So I tried with an object and also with pointer

`cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> classifier = cv::ml::SVM::create()
   map<string,classifier> class_classifier`

and

`cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> classifier = cv::ml::SVM::create()
   map<string,classifier*> class_classifier`

But both seem like to be in error.

> 'classifier' cannot appear in a constant expression

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: what is the meaning of "not working" ? If there are errors include them in the question

Comment: "So I tried with an object and also with pointer" template parameters of map are types not values....

Comment: @ user463035818 my bad.. I will edit

Comment: @ user463035818 So what should the type be for this case, Ptr??

Comment: whats wrong with `map<string,cv::ml::SVM>` ? or is `CvSVM` just a typedef of `cv::ml::SVM` ?

Comment: please the full error message. If your compiler produces an error message only saying ""second is a copy of the second object" then it is broken :P

Comment: @user463035818 . sorry will post when back. have to leave in hurry.. std::__cvv::basic::string<char>, cv::ml::SVM> ::second' to be of abstract type 'cv::ml::SVM

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
map<string,classifier> class_classifier
```

wont work, because you cannot use a value where a type is expected. To illustrate it on something hopefully more obvious, if you wanted to create a mapping of strings to string, then you would also not do this:

```
std::string x = "hello world";
std::map<std::string, x> my_map; // non-sense !
```

If you want to map strings to `cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM>` then the correct declartion is:

```
std::map<std::string, cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> > my_map;
```